# A symbol on page 302 of Goldblatt's "Topoi [. . .]".

Tags: notation, topos-theory

I'm reading Goldblatt's *"Topoi: A Categorial Analysis of Logic."*

There's a symbol I don't recognise on page 302 of the copy with International Standard Book Number 0-486-45026-0. It's in the definition of a natural number object and resembles a cross between $s$ and $\sigma$.

For lack of a better format to show you what it is, here is a picture:

[image: Natural number object symbol].

**I have tried using Detexify but to no avail.**

> What symbol is it?

Please help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That symbol looks like a [cursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursive) letter s (lower case).

Comment: From that Wikipedia article:   Cursive has been in decline throughout the 21st century due to its perceived lack of necessity. The largest teachers' union in Fairfax County, Virginia, has called cursive a "dying art"

Comment: Your answer would make sense in the context. The motivating example for an nno talks of the successor function on the natural numbers, denoted $s$. Thank you :)